# libbulldog null pointer exception on createBoard()

Tags: java, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am working on a class project that involves controlling pins on the beagle bone black, it is running the stock debian os.

I added the library and was able to have the following code work.

Code:

```
package swerve.tracker.robot;

import org.bulldog.beagleboneblack.BBBNames;
import org.bulldog.beagleboneblack.gpio.BBBPwm;
import org.bulldog.core.gpio.Pin;
import org.bulldog.core.gpio.Pwm;
import org.bulldog.core.platform.Board;
import org.bulldog.core.platform.Platform;
import org.bulldog.core.util.BulldogUtil;
import org.bulldog.devices.servo.Servo;

/**
 * Created by yoseph on 5/10/2016.
 */
public class Robot {
    private Board board;
    public void init() {
        //board = Platform.createBoard();
        //Pwm pwm = board.getPin(BBBNames.ECAPPWM0_P9_42).as(Pwm.class);
        //Servo servo = new Servo(pwm);
        //servo.setAngle(180.0f);
        System.out.println("Started");
        BulldogUtil.sleepMs(1000);
        System.out.println("Waited 1 second.");
        //servo.setAngle(90.0f);
        //BulldogUtil.sleepMs(1000);
        System.out.println("Waited another second.");
        //servo.setAngle(0.0f);
        //BulldogUtil.sleepMs(1000);
        System.out.println("Finished initializing.");
    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void finish() {
    }

    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }
}
```

Console Out:

```
yoseph1998@beaglebone:~/.../$ java -jar SwerveTracker.jar
Started
Waited 1 second.
Waited another second.
Finished initializing.
```

Once I uncomment `Board board = Platform.createBoard()` I get a `NullPointerException` from the library caused by that line, I've searched online for this problem and found nothing, I followed the examples and guides and found nothing. Here is the error.

Console Out:

```
yoseph1998@beaglebone:~/.../$ java -jar SwerveTracker.jar
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:459)
    at org.bulldog.core.platform.AbstractBoard.setProperty(AbstractBoard.java:94)
    at org.bulldog.beagleboneblack.BeagleBoneBlack.createProperties(BeagleBoneBlack.java:265)
    at org.bulldog.beagleboneblack.BeagleBoneBlack.<init>(BeagleBoneBlack.java:33)
    at org.bulldog.beagleboneblack.BeagleBoneBlackBoardFactory.createBoard(BeagleBoneBlackBoardFactory.java:17)
    at org.bulldog.core.platform.Platform.createBoard(Platform.java:13)
    at swerve.tracker.robot.Robot.init(Robot.java:18)
    at swerve.tracker.robot.framework.Scheduler.run(Scheduler.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could anyone help, if not then does anyone have any recommendatons on a better library than libbulldog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am running this as a java program it has the guest user permission. Any file that requires root access the program won't be able to read or write to. When the program calls the `Platform.createBoard()` it tries to access the `/etc/dogtag` as ekaerovets mentioned.

There are two ways to fix this:

- Chnage the permission on the file to be read only. But then other methods and functions that need to access files with permission will also fail.
- Give the program sudo permission. This is the best option because it means the library will be able to access what it was designed to access.

### Solution

Run the program with sudo permission as follows

```
sudo java -jar SwerveTracker.jar
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Hashtable we have:

```
    if (value == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(); // 495
    }
```

It seems, we have null as Hashtable value.

Go back to BeagleBoneBlack.createProperties:265

```
    if(new File("/etc/dogtag").exists()) {
        setProperty(BBBProperties.DOGTAG, BulldogUtil.readFileAsString("/etc/dogtag"));
    }
```

It looks like BulldogUtil.readFileAsString returns null.

```
public static String readFileAsString(String path) { 
    try {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, Charset.defaultCharset());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Looks like we get an exception while trying to read file /etc/dogtag. And that's where my magic ends because Exception is lost inside readFileAsString.

What I suggest is

1. Put a breakpoint inside catch clause to see the root cause.
2. Check that you have enough access to the file

Comment: Alright. I will look into that file, check if it exists and the permissions on it.

Comment: The permission on that file was only owner can read and write (600) so I changed it to only owner can write and execute, but anyone can read (644).